# Google OpenID Connect: Not receiving "auth_time" claim when supplying the "max_age" parameter to an authentication request

Tags: google-oauth, google-signin, google-openid

I am sending max_age parameter in the auth request and the response does not have the auth_time claim as per https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthRequest

I was expecting it to follow the OIDC Spec where an authentication request contains the max_age field:

> the ID Token returned MUST include an auth_time Claim Value